# How to remove huge number of selected rows from TableView?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Got TableView, lets say there are 10.000 rows. Selected almost all of them, and wanna remove by clicking a button. How to mange it without javafx GUI delay?

Right now i got:

```
ObservableList aLLinTable = tableView.getItems()
               selected = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()

aLLinTable .removeAll(selected)
```

Think the problem is with type of items in TableView - ObservableList collection. Changes on it causes firing action. As well im removing huge number  of objects from collection so there are searching/removing loop.
Maybe i should use

```
ObservableList<Integer> selectedIndices = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices()
```

and then
removing from aLLinTable collection by indexes:

```
for(Integer idx : selectedIndices) {
   aLLinTable.remove(idx.intValue())
}
```

Didnt tested it yet, but still it will work on ObservableList collection aLLinTable.

So maybe copy/convery aLLinTable collection to .. ArrayList, make on it for-loop, and then re-create ObservableList and .setItems() on TableView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use HashMap, remove from it objects with proper keys and then convert map to ObservableList and set it to TableView.setItems().

It working very quick. Tested with 5000-10000 rows.